# Gosebier- a unique style

Tags: recipe, beer-styles

Dose anyone have any experience brewing Gosebier?  Its a german wheat style of beer that is flavored with some salt (and citrus I believe).  I had one at the Golden City Brewery in Denver a couple years back and loved it.  But I need a little more research before trying to replicate one myself.  This is one of those quietly unheard of beer styles.

Anyone? Anyone?
Cheers

Comment: Cleaning up tags: Changed recipes -> recipe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this good descriptor at [BeerAdvocate Gose](http://beeradvocate.com/beer/style/16).

Rather than inocculating with Lactobacillus this descriptor mentions the addition of lactic acid directly to the boil.

The only semi-commercial source for this that I have found was the one I had in Denver, but BA also lists several examples at the link above including one from Dog Fish Head....

[DFH Goser the Gosarian](http://www.dogfish.com/brews-spirits/the-brews/brewpub-exclusives/goser-the-gosarian.htm).
Luckily it was last produced during august of 2009, but it was only available at the brewpub in Rehoboth.

So far then its salt, corriander, 50-60% wheat malt.  The perhaps there is some lactic acid, and I'd assume some german ale yeast.  DFH mentions the use of flaked oats too.

**EDIT 4/15/2011  I am still very interested in making a good Gose.  BYO magazine just did a nice article on the style with a couple good recipes to start with.  I might have to go with that as a meaningful starting point.**

Answer (score 5):

Brew Your Own recently did a feature on the Gose (Gosebier) style.

You can find the full article [here](http://byo.com/component/resource/article/Indices/11-Beer%20Styles/2429-gose) as well as the all-grain and extract with grain recipe's.

I have copied the all grain recipe here:

> **There She Gose Again**
>   (5 gallons/19 L, all-grain)
>   OG = 1.048
>   FG = 1.012
>   IBU = 12
>   SRM = 4
>   ABV = 4.7%
>
> **Ingredients**:
>   5 lbs. (2.3 kg) wheat malt
>   3.25 lbs. (1.5 kg) German Pilsner malt (2 °L)
>   2.0 lbs. (0.91 kg) acidulated malt (2 °L)
>   0.50 lbs (0.23 kg) rice hulls
>   2.8 AAU Santiam hops (60 min.) (0.5 oz./14 g of 5.6% alpha acids) 1 tsp Irish moss or 1 Whirlfloc® tablet (15 min.)
>   1.0 oz (28 g) ground coriander seed (10 min.)
>   0.75 oz (21 g) sea salt (10 min.) White Labs WLP029 (German Ale/Kölsch Yeast) or Wyeast 1007 (German Ale) yeast
>   0.75 cup (150 g) priming sugar
>
> **Step by Step**:
>   Mill the grains, but be
>   sure to keep the acidulated malt
>   separate. Do not mill the rice hulls.
>   Dough in all but the acidulated malt
>   using 4.0 gallons (15 L) of water with
>   a target mash holding temperature of
>   149 °F (65 °C). Hold the mash
>   temperature for approximately 60
>   minutes or until the conversion is
>   complete. Add the acidulated malt to
>   the mash for an additional 45 minutes.
>   Try to keep the temperature as close
>   to original mash temperature as
>   possible using an available heat
>   source. Anything between 144–149 °F
>   (62–65 °C) will work. Raise the
>   temperature of the mash to 168 °F (76
>   °C) and begin sparging with 170 °F (77
>   °C) water until you collect 6.0
>   gallons (23 L) of wort in the kettle.
>        The total wort boiling time for this recipe is 60 minutes. At the
>   onset of a full rolling boil, add your
>   scheduled hop addition. When there are
>   15 minutes remaining in the boil, be
>   sure to add your Irish moss or
>   Whirlfloc® tablet to help with
>   precipitation of the hot break.  At 10
>   minutes remaining, add both the ground
>   coriander seed and the salt.
>        Cool the wort to 68 °F (20 °C), transfer to your fermentation vessel
>   and aerate the wort adequately. Add
>   the contents of your yeast starter to
>   the chilled wort. Ferment around 68 °F
>   (20 °C) until the final gravity is
>   reached, which should be in 5 to 7
>   days. Rack to a secondary vessel and
>   allow the beer to mature another 5 to
>   7 days around the same temperature.
>   Your beer is now ready to rack into a
>   keg or bottles along with the priming
>   sugar.

Answer (score 4):

I found this today...

http://hopwild.com/2009/08/21/allday-beer-gose-recipe/comment-page-1/

Answer (score 2):

http://www.brewboard.com/index.php?showtopic=68606&hl=gose  There's a link which contains Randy Moshers recipe for the Gose in Radical Brewing.

Comment: Interestingly all the recipes listed in that forum make use of acidulated/sour malt.  Which makes sense.  Regardless of tradition (or antiquated practices), using the addition of an ingredient to get an effect rather than the variability of an organism to get a hint of sourness would make more sense.  And thats what acidulated malt was created to do, serve as an acid adjuster but still be purity law legal. Good link

Comment: Heh, don't forget you are using the variability of an organism to ferment your beer.  Also the characteristic of lactobacillus is different than adding lactic acid, and you can usually taste that difference. A sour mash is simple, and then you boil it, killing off the lactobacillus.  The sourness locked in, no additional lacto changes after that point.  I haven't personally used acidulated malt but I hear it works pretty well. BTW, Purity law is way overrated and only served to hinder the development of beer.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way that historically Gosebier used lactic acid.  It most definitely was a lactobacillus thing.  If you want to learn more about Gosebier, talk to Jeff at Golden City... he's a nice guy and has read up on the history and he's tried a few different methods, I'm sure he'd be willing to share. It's generally made with coriander(the citrusy flavor) and salt. Radical Brewing by Randy Mosher is where Jeff first learned of it I believe.  There is a commercially produced one that you see from time to time here from Germany, but I kinda prefer Golden City's.  Also, as of the last two years, Gose is now an official style at the GABF.

Comment: I have had the Gose at Golden City as I stated in my question.  Its interesting that lactic character gets mentioned at all, because I do not recall there being any lactic character in the Golden City version....regardless of its source.

Comment: His first batch didn't have any at all, which is what you probably had.  Last couple have...

Comment: His first batch was lactic/lacto free.  He's been talking about doing a sour mash, but I can't recall what he's done in the past couple batches.  Probably some lactobacillus... you should ask him.

Answer (score 1):

From Beer-News.org today, (Portland, OR) – Upright Brewing will release two beers at the brewery on Sunday: Upright Gose and Billy the Mountain. Here is the scoop straight from the brewery:

“Bottle Release Party for Billy the Mountain (old ale) and Gose
1/10/09 1-6pm at the Upright tasting room (@ Leftbank Project, 240 N. Broadway, Portland)

On Sunday January 10 we will be releasing our newest limited bottlings including the highly anticipated traditional old ale ‘Billy the Mountain’. It’s batch number one for Upright, being brewed in March and having matured in pinot noir barrels with a special strain of brettanomyces yeast. Only 50 cases will be available and we’ll have the only keg of this Frank Zappa inspired beer on tap.

We’re also releasing our ‘Gose’ beer. It’s an unusual German-style of wheat beer that is slightly soured and uses coriander and salt. For those interested in learning more check out [Angelo’s great post about the style](http://brewpublic.com/oregon-beer/thats-the-way-it-gose/).

The release will be during our normal tasting room hours that day of 1-6 pm. Charcuterie tailored to the two beers will be put out along with some bread to snack on.”

Comment: maybe this style is slowly starting to get recognized.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't heard of it until now, but here's a [google translated netherlands wikipedia page](http://bit.ly/6jZa75) about it.

Here's [a longer page](http://www.germanbeerguide.co.uk/gose.html) about the history of the style and one person's quest to find it as well as some tasting notes that may be of help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [review of that beer](http://www.scribd.com/doc/14597768/The-Oredigger-Issue-03-September-17-2007) in a newspaper. It's on page 10. If nothing else it might help you get to the same taste and look of the beer you had tried.

Answer (score 0):

Thought I would revive this since...

I was in Charleston SC last week and found a bottle of Gose Bier at the Charleston Beer Exchange.  It's not cheap but its straight from Lipsig.