# Making a gose (salt in beer?)

Tags: beer, recipe, additives

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Gosebier- a unique style](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1080/gosebier-a-unique-style)

I recently fell in love with the [Gose style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gose) of sour wheat beers (similar to a Gueze), thanks to kegs of Bayerische Bahnhof invading my town. Naturally, I immediately wanted to make one!

Gose beers are normally made with coriander and salt. I haven't yet brewed with herbs, and adding salt to the mix is totally crazy in my head.

Any advice on amounts to use for a five-gallon batch? Timing? -- ie. boil, primary, secondary?

Comment: [This recipe](http://www.themadfermentationist.com/2010/10/sour-leipziger-gose-recipe.html) has 14g Sea Salt and 14g Corriander added with 5 min left.

Comment: Gose isn't similar to a Geuze at all. Geuze is a blend of old and young Lambic beer. Gose is an awesome beer in it's own right though (and probably a million times easier to make than a Geuze).